# How to call a function that is using window.onload from another function

Tags: javascript, function, return

I'm trying to use questionFunction() again once the user clicks a button which calls myFunction but I'm getting an error 'questionFunction is not defined'

```
window.onload = function questionFunction() {
  var questionText = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = randomNumber1 + " " + operationArray[randomOperation1] + " " + randomNumber2 + " " + operationArray[randomOperation2] + " " + randomNumber3;
}

function myFunction() {
return questionFunction();
}
```

I wan't the text to be changed on load and also again once the user clicks to call myFunction()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function questionFunction() {
  var questionText = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = randomNumber1 + " " + operationArray[randomOperation1] + " " + randomNumber2 + " " + operationArray[randomOperation2] + " " + randomNumber3;
}

window.onload = questionFunction;

function myFunction() {
  return questionFunction();
}
```

This will work.
You're getting error because of wrong function scope.

You can read about it here:

https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because a function *expression* doesn't add an identifier for the function to the scope where it appears (only function *declarations* do that).

The simple answer is to make that a function declaration instead:

```
function questionFunction() {
  var questionText = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = randomNumber1 + " " + operationArray[randomOperation1] + " " + randomNumber2 + " " + operationArray[randomOperation2] + " " + randomNumber3;
}
window.onload = questionFunction;
```

Since that adds an identifier for the function, now you can call it the way you do in `myFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare questionFuntion, and reuse this function where you want

```
function questionFunction() {
    var questionText = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = randomNumber1 + " " + operationArray[randomOperation1] + " " + randomNumber2 + " " + operationArray[randomOperation2] + " " + randomNumber3;
}
window.onload = questionFunction;

function myFunction() {
    return questionFunction();
}
```